# SQL Server 2017 - Using Multiple Sequences to create unique Identifiers, or?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sequence

(I apologize in advance for my ignorance on SQL - I was put on a database building project at work because I'm the "tech guy" but have little to no experience actually *building them*)

I am trying to build an inventory system that is as automated as possible and uses barcode scanning + custom barcodes for the bulk of identification. I am wondering if using multiple sequences to keep track of how many unique instances of each type of item that exists in stock is a good idea, or if there is a better way.

Example: I want to put 50 unique rows for 50 new laptops into the table 'instock.' Using a field with a foreign key in another table ('itemtype') the prefix would be 'laptop_'. I would like to add an auto-increment ending starting at '001' to '050' so each one will have a unique barcode of 'laptop_001, laptop_002, laptop_003, etc.' *These have to be unique since each laptop has it's own unique serial code/will be checked in and out*.

However, I have several types of items I would need to do this for. Desks, tables, monitors, cables, computer accessories, pens, markers, etc. This could easily get into the 100s of types of items. All these different types would be in one table, 'instock'.

Would creating sequences for each item type be feasible or would it cause too much stress on the DB to use? Should I just make a one-to-one table linked to 'itemtype' and use an int field that gets updated with every new entry to determine this instead? Or is there a better way? The organization (a non-profit) can't afford actual devs, mostly "hire" volunteers, and my contract is only a year so I want something that they don't need to change for a loooong time. Thank you for your time and considerations.

Comment: Is it vital, that the codes have the type in them? Why not just a number and if you want to know, what type that number is look it up in the DB? (If you cannot already tell by looking at it.) Regarding "stress on the DB":  As we're talking about a non-profit organization, which cannot "afford actual devs", I assume the traffic of items isn't really vast, or is it? I'd rather had an issue with the fact, that a sequence for each type required a new sequence, each time a new item type is introduced. That is, something, that is typically a DML only thing all of a sudden requires a DDL.

Comment: Or what about a number, that is unique amongst all items, yet for the creation of the barcodes is concatenated with some type identifier, if that really needs to be in that code?

Comment: Sticky - The people using this aren't very familiar with computers; One of the specific requests was to make barcodes that use "real" words, like "laptop_001" and not "inv0001" or "00001" that can be easily read. They really REALLY want each to have their own so they can visually see "laptop_001" and "laptop_002", as "laptop_001" and "laptop_030" would be too confusing for them. Otherwise I would love to do one shared unique number that's just concatenated for every entry.

Comment: Hmm, I see... Well this is not a "technical hint", but: Tell them, that what they want requires to hire a technician every time a new item type is introduced and remind them of the costs. Sometimes customers can easily accept any former absolute no-go in an instant, if you remind them of the costs behind the alternatives.

Comment: Sticky - I will bring that all up with them but I'm not optimistic, I get the feeling they will just tell me to make the front end send a "create sequence" statement when a new item type is made. Thank you very much for replying, I'll see what I can do.

Comment: Another question: What if they have, say four laptops in the beginning, so laptop_001, laptop_002, laptop_003 and laptop_004. Now laptop_002 is broken and thrown away. For some time no replacement is acquired. Then they buy a new laptop. Will they also insist, that this reuses the laptop_002 number? Or do they even want, that the laptop_003 and laptop_004 get "down shifted" at the time of the loss? I mean if not (which would be very reasonable) they would eventually have gaps in their numbers anyway.

Comment: Sticky - laptop_002 will always exist with information about when it was broken and thrown away in the db due to org rules. If they added a new one, it will be added as the next number in the sequence, so laptop_004. I've designed the db to never allow users to access the data itself, only certain stored procedures and views. Data can never be deleted  (and rarely updated) by anyone other than the db owner aka me until I quit/am fired :)

Comment: Whoops, I mean the next one will  be added as laptop_005, not 4, sorry!

Comment: @stickybit regardless of how it gets resolved thanks for your help. I'll bring up all of this at the next meeting with my bosses.